# Linking C library to R

Tags: c, r, makefile, libxlsxwriter

I recently found this C library (http://libxlsxwriter.github.io/), and attempted to use it with R.

Getting the C library to work by itself was not difficult. I downloaded `zlib` and `libxlsxwriter` using `msys2`, and ran `make` in the `libxlsxwriter` folder.

Now I can run this Hello-World example, lets call it `test.c`:

```
#include "xlsxwriter.h"
void main() {
  lxw_workbook  *workbook  = workbook_new("myexcel.xlsx");
  lxw_worksheet *worksheet = workbook_add_worksheet(workbook, NULL);
  int row = 0;
  int col = 0;
  worksheet_write_string(worksheet, row, col, "Hello me!", NULL);
  workbook_close(workbook);
}
```

Now I can compile `test.c` by running:

```
cc test.c -o test -lxlsxwriter -lz
```

And then run the executable:

```
./test
```

And now I have a Hello-World excel document.

Getting it to work with R has been much trickier. If I simply run:

```
R CMD SHLIB test.c
```

I get this error: `ibxlsxwriter/include/xlsxwriter/common.h:19:42: fatal error: xlsxwriter/third_party/queue.h: No such file or directory
 #include "xlsxwriter/third_party/queue.h"`

Yet the file is clearly there when I check.

Any advice on how to connect this C library with R? At this point I am just trying to get the hello-world example to run from R.

Would it be a better approach to start out building a package, with `xlsxwriter` in the `inst` folder, and then try to write a `makevars` that will get `xlsxwriter` to compile correctly? I know I would have to include `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/libxlsxwriter` but I am guessing I would need more than that.

Comment: Check out `R CMD config` looking for the `SHLIB_*` variables; set these to point in the appropriate locations before running `R CMD SHLIB`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try Continuum's Anaconda R packages. They use MSYS2 packages fairly directly. The toolchain package is called m2w64-toolchain and the posix package is sometimes useful for building R packages too.

`conda install -c r r-essentials m2w64-toolchain posix`

Disclaimer: I work for Continuum, but I also work on MSYS2.